# Using np.where with OOP

Tags: python, numpy, oop

I have create an numpy array in which all the cells values are objects. I want to use np.where conditions but it is not working as I want to check the equivalent conditions for object attributes. The object class looks similar to the one below:

```
class Cell():
     def __init__(self):
         self.value = 'ABC'
     def __repr__(self):
         return self.value
```

Now I have 2D numpy array with all the cell equivalent to this cell class, and I want to check if cell.value == 'ABC'.
The numpy array look like,

```
array([[M, M, M, M],
       [M, 'ABC', M, M],
       [M, M, M, M],
       [M, M, M, 'ABC'],
       [M, M, M, M]], dtype=object)
```

If I try to run np.where(temp == 'ABC'), I get the following output:

```
(array([], dtype=int64), array([], dtype=int64))
```

And if I run the command np.where(temp.value == 'ABC'), I get the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-073cbaaed538> in <module>
----> 1 np.where(temp.value =='ABC')

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'value'
```

How can I use np.where with OOP?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] to show which code isn’t behaving how you’d want it to, and what specifically is going wrong.

Comment: `np.where(cond)` just looks for `True/False` (technically non-zero) values in `cond`.  So what is does depends entirely on what the `arg==value` expression produces.  In you have an array of `Cell` objects, `arr.value` does not work.  An array of such objects has few, if any, advantages over a list ot the same.

Comment: just to let you know, `numpy` is really not designed around handling the case of object dtypes. You should avoid object dtypes in your code if possible, even if just to switch to processing with built in types. Now, you *could* use structured dtypes instead of object, depending on what you want out of your class

Comment: You are comparing with an `str` type with a `<class '__main__.Cell'>` type. Just just use `arr.astype(str)` to change the type and compare with `np.where`. Check my answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing with an object ('ABC') from `str` class with an object from  `'__main__.Cell'` class. (try checking with `type(Cell())`

A fix is simply changing type with `np.array.astype()`

```
arr = np.array([['M', Cell(),'M'], 
                ['M', Cell(),'M'], 
                [Cell(),'M' ,'M']])

np.where(arr.astype(str)=='ABC')
```

```
(array([0, 1, 2]), array([1, 1, 0]))
```

---

**Additionally,**

You can check type of each element individually in your array by -

```
np.vectorize(type)(arr)
```

```
array([[<class 'str'>, <class '__main__.Cell'>, <class 'str'>],
       [<class 'str'>, <class '__main__.Cell'>, <class 'str'>],
       [<class '__main__.Cell'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>]],
      dtype=object)
```

Notice, that some of them are objects of class `str` which you want to use for comparison but others are `Cell` class objects.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to traverse through the whole array to check if something is equal to 'ABC'. The code for the same is below:

```
m =[]
for i in range(temp.shape[0]):
    m.append([])
    for j in range(temp.shape[1]):
        m[i].append(temp[i,j].value == 'ABC')
np.where(m)
```

In this case, you won't have the computation advantage of using np.where, as you need to traverse through the whole array using for loops.

Comment: You've given up a lot of the advantage wit regards to speed by using `object` dtype. In CPython, everything is a pointer to something else. Numpy works with fixed-sized buffers, object dtype basically just means arbitrary (size included) objects. Basically it is handled as an array of pointers.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [38]: class Cell():
    ...:      def __init__(self):
    ...:          self.value = 'ABC'
    ...:      def __repr__(self):
    ...:          return self.value
    ...:
```

A list of these objects:

```
In [39]: alist = [Cell(),Cell(),Cell()]
In [40]: [c.value for c in alist]
Out[40]: ['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC']
In [41]: alist.value
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-41-e136813b0fd2>", line 1, in <module>
    alist.value
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'value'
```

An array of the same:

```
In [42]: arr = np.array(alist)
In [43]: arr
Out[43]: array([ABC, ABC, ABC], dtype=object)
In [44]: arr.value
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-44-bfedc572e969>", line 1, in <module>
    arr.value
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'value'
```

Same problem as with this list. Just because the elements have some attribute, it does not mean that a list or array has that attribute.  That's not how Python's OOP works.

```
In [45]: [c.value for c in arr]
Out[45]: ['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC']
```

An alternative to the list comprehension:

```
In [46]: np.frompyfunc(lambda x: x.value, 1,1)(arr)
Out[46]: array(['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC'], dtype=object)
```

This may be convenient in some cases, but it is not faster.